# Qt send QbyteArray data to python

Tags: python, django, qt, serial-port

I have a device which will produce a large amount of data because of some specific operation. These data will be sent through RS232 serial port to PC. I want to use the library `QSerialPort` of Qt to receive these data and then send these data to a python program for display (such as a web page of Django).

The question is how to send data (`QByteArray` or char) to Python program? Using SIP to extend my Qt program for Python? Or through network socket? Or any other solution for my situation?

In addition, I gave up the library `pySerial` because this library is unstable in my project.

Comment: `pySerial` is widely used and should work well, how did it fail?

Comment: @figs: I use pySerial in Ubuntu, and send some data to my device, and the device can receive the data, sometimes it is correct, but sometimes the received data are all zero. If I use Cutecom ( Ubuntu serial port tool), the data can be sent to device correctly. Therefore I thought it is unstable.

Comment: It possibly could be a problem with how you're using it (e.g. not waiting long enough for bytes to arrive before reading the port). `pySerial` should be fine. It would be interesting if it really was broken on your PC.

Comment: @figs: My device was STM32F4 and the program is written by C. It is correct when I use Cutecom or other tool. But it is sometimes incorrect sometimes correct when I use **pySerial**. I want to report this situation but  I didn't find where to go.

Comment: Post it as a question here on stack overflow :)

Comment: @figs: Thanks! I will do it.